# Getting access token for calling Google Cloud Management APIs through POSTMan or Fiddler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, oauth2-playground

I am trying to get access token (bearer token) for calling Google Cloud Audit Logs API (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list).

I want to try this in POSTMan so that I can use these raw HTTP calls through a script on a schedule.

I am making following GET call from POSTMan to get access token.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.read&redirect_uri=https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground&response_type=token&client_id=<my-client-id>.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=online
```

Although I am getting `200 OK` response back, response doesn't include the access token.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Mahesh.

Comment: Why do you expect that to work? Whose Client ID? Is the Redirect URI set up for that Client ID. As an addition point, the URL parameters are not set up correctly. Read this article to see how to do this in CURL. This will show you the correct URI to set up. https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/ which is a two step request flow. A browser is involved (mandatory unless you already have a refresh token and the original request was `access_type=offline`

Comment: Here is a link to show you how to do this in PowerShell with some additional tricks: https://www.jhanley.com/powershell-impersonate-google-service-account/

Comment: Have you tried $gcloud auth application-default print-access-token command? More information about this command can be found here:  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token